# how to realize a queue in java?

Tags: java, queue

I want to do the same thing I did in this code for stack 
how can i change it so it will be for queue? I don't want to use stack or LinkedList for that

```
    public StackAsArray(){
        this(new DynamicArray());
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {

    }
    public void push(Object o) {

    }
    public Object pop() {

    }
}
```

Comment: By thinking about your homework assignment and trying. Instead of dumping some code and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace your `push` and `pop` methods with `enqueue` and `dequeue` methods.

`enqueue` adds elements to the end of the array, while `dequeue` will remove it from the beginning.

```
public class QueueAsArray implements Queue {
    ...

    public void enqueue(Object o) {
        arr.set(numOfElements, o);
        numOfElements++;
    }

    public Object dequeue() {
        if(isEmpty()) {  // an empty check is a MUST
            return null; 
        }

        numOfElements = numOfElements - 1;
        Object res = arr.get(0);
        arr.set(0, null); // not 100% sure this works, but since this is a homework question, its upto you to figure out. The logic is to remove the 0th element.
        return res;
    }
}
```